# Python 3.4: replace "0x" with "\x" in a List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Hi I want to replace "0x" with "\x" in this list:

```
['0x50', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
```

I tried it with this list comprehension:

```
result = ['0x50', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
result = [x.replace("0x","\x") for x in result]
```

But it gives me this Error:

```
(unicode error)"unicodeescape" codex cant decode byte in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

How can I change "0x" and "\x" now?

Comment: it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096). Could you provide some context: where does the data come from? How do you want to use the results? I sense, it is possible to streamline the whole process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a raw string as in

```
>>> l = ['0x50', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
>>> [i.replace('0x',r'\x') for i in l]
['\\x50', '\\x0', '\\x0', '\\x0']
```

Or double-escape `\` as in

```
>>> [i.replace('0x','\\x') for i in l]
['\\x50', '\\x0', '\\x0', '\\x0']
```